# Serving SPA from API server

Tags: javascript, rest, architecture, client-server, single-page-application

From what I understand, the de facto method of serving an SPA is by implementing a catch all method for GET requests. So what happens if I both host the API and serve the SPA from the same server, and need to retrieve a resource e.g. `/users`?

How do you handle routing API calls/resources in a setup where your API server is serving your SPA?

e.g. using express:

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist')));


// Conflict here  <---------------------
app.get('/users', (req,res) => {
  // respond with users 
})

// And here       <---------------------
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist', 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on ${process.env.PORT || port}`)
})
```

Intuition tells me to implement a catch all for GET requests for the SPA while implementing an exception to the `/api` resource for API calls. But then there's the problem of accessing the `/api` through the browser.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add good idea would be adding `api` prefix to your rest API endpoints. Like `/api/users` for your user api.